# Ellipsize three dots before certain characters

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

Is is possible to customise Android Ellipsize property to show three dots before some desired characters count from the end.

For example if my text is "Hello World" but my textview can't show the whole text and I want to preserve last 2 characters exact. So the output I want is something like "Hell...ld"

Comment: Doesnt android:ellipsize="middle" wok for you?

Comment: I wan to control the exact count of character from last to be displayed